# Upgrading to Rails 6.1.4: `to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-upgrade

I am upgrading my existing application of rails `5.2.0` to `6.1.4`

I followed the [official upgrade guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#the-upgrade-process) as well as, [this guide](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/rails/upgrades/upgrade-rails-from-5-2-to-6-0.html).

My rails version is `6.1.4.1` & my ruby version is `2.5.3` which satisfies the condition of running the app. Anybody could give me help on the directions of how to solve this issue ?

The problem, though, is when I try to run the server I get the following error:

```
> > Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.4.1 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    19: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    18: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    17: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    15: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    14: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    13: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    12: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    11: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    10: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
     9: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
     8: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
     7: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
     6: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
     5: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
     4: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
     3: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
     2: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
     1: from /Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:117:in `new_from_string'
/Users/heron/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:233:in `to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: Looks like your `config.ru` file is invalid.

Comment: Well, All I did is changed `run Rails.application` to `Rails.application.load_server
` after running the rails app:update task.

But that's right, changing it back made it work.